# Android: Saving ListView items and load/add more

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, onscroll

I'm trying to load some number of more items in my ListView when I scroll to the bottom and just **ADD** them to the current ones. It works well, but recently I found out that it loads **ALL** objects again, only with more items. I'm using Parse.com. I discovered, that Parse.com provides their own custom ParseQueryAdapter, which contains getNextPageView() method. It loads move items, but only when the user clicks on the button below. I also tried `.setSkip(someNumber)` method but it only erases/hides `someNumber` of items in the top. So I still want to use `OnScrollListener` and really **load-more** and not load-again+more.

Do you have any idea, how to do it?

check my codes:

```
public void updateData() {
         mListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);     
   final ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);


    query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
    query.orderByAscending("animal");


    query.setLimit(mListView.getCount() + 5);


    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

        @Override
          public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

              if(animals != null){
                  mAdapter.clear();

                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);  
            footie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {


                      mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));
                    ArrayList<Animal> animal = new ArrayList<Animal>();
                    animal.add(animals.get(i));






                  }  

              }  
            }
         }); }






     private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();  }

         @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                return null;



         }


         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


               mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);

               mEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_animal);

               mAdapter = new AnimalAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Animal>());

               mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
               mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




               mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                            int totalItemCount) {
                        final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                        if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {




                        if (mListView.getCount() > 20) {

                            RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);

                            mListView.removeFooterView(footie);

                              }





                            else{

                                    updateData();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear `Adapter` before setting it to `ListView` like as follows:

```
public void updateData() {
         mListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);     
   final ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);


    query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
    query.orderByAscending("animal");


    query.setLimit(mListView.getCount() + 5);


    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

        @Override
          public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

              if(animals != null){
                  mAdapter.clear();

                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);  
            footie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mAdapter.clear();///////HERE

            for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {


                      mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));
                    ArrayList<Animal> animal = new ArrayList<Animal>();
                    animal.add(animals.get(i));






                  }  

              }  
            }
         }); }






     private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();  }

         @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                return null;



         }


         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


               mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);

               mEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_animal);

               mAdapter = new AnimalAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Animal>());

               mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
               mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




               mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                            int totalItemCount) {
                        final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                        if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {




                        if (mListView.getCount() > 20) {

                            RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);

                            mListView.removeFooterView(footie);

                              }





                            else{

                                    updateData();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

You are only adding items without wiping previous data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Osama!! It worked well. Btw dont you have idea, how to check, if the objects in ListView/Adapter didnt change? Or to check total number of ParseQuery items? Ive done query.count(); but it appears to be very slow, so I think that it does that method more than once or so. And why? Because I need to set statement if(mListView.getCount() == ParseQuery number of objects) -> do something

Comment: Could you cancel my answer as accepted answer, then refresh page & then reaccept my answer & refresh page. I did not get 15 reps.

Comment: OkaY, I did it. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Ask a new question, I'll try to answer there because it is a new question.

Comment: Okay. By the way, what the method mAdapter.clear() put 2 times actually does? I dont understand it at all

Comment: If you want you can remove this one `if(animals != null){
                  mAdapter.clear();`.